# How to avoid the looping data in Phpmyadmin after selecting a three different tables in database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

When I selected data with different rows from three different tables, it suddenly duplicates, I should only fetch 4 rows but it became 25 rows, I've already used `DISTINCT` but it didn't work.

This is my SELECT statement:

```
SELECT seller.s_fname,
       seller.trade_name,
       order_details.od_id,
       order_details.customer_id,
       order_details.confirmation_status,
       food_product.food_id,
       food_product.food_name,
       food_product.f_image
FROM   seller
INNER JOIN order_details
       ON seller.seller_id=order_details.seller_id
INNER JOIN food_product
       ON seller.seller_id=food_product.seller_id
WHERE  seller.seller_id=order_details.seller_id
AND    customer_id = '" . $_SESSION['customer_id'] .  "'
AND    notif_status = 'uncleared'
AND    od_status = 'ordered'
```

How can I avoid the duplicates?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe two things you can try to avoid duplicates on your request :

- In your WHERE clause you put again `seller.seller_id=order_details.seller_id`. It's already in your INNER JOIN CLAUSE above. **Try to withdraw it.**
- Try to use *GROUP BY* clause with seller_ids.

You can try this edited SQL query :

```
SELECT seller.seller_id,
   seller.s_fname,
   seller.trade_name,
   order_details.od_id,
   order_details.customer_id,
   order_details.confirmation_status,
   food_product.food_id,
   food_product.food_name,
   food_product.f_image
   FROM   seller
   INNER JOIN order_details
   ON seller.seller_id=order_details.seller_id
   INNER JOIN food_product
   ON seller.seller_id=food_product.seller_id
   WHERE  customer_id = '" . $_SESSION['customer_id'] .  "'
   AND    notif_status = 'uncleared'
   AND    od_status = 'ordered'
   GROUP BY seller.seller_id
```

Comment: oh sir, it does not fetch other data now, it just selects the three seller :3 it should now fetch 10 values and not only 3 values :(